# RecyclerView showing data after closing and coming back to activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView to show data that is fetching from firebase Realtime Database. When I am opening recycler view activity it is showing nothing but when I go to previous activity come again then it is showing.

THIS IS THE ACTIVITY IN WHICH DATA HAS TO BE SHOWN-

```
   public class BrakesItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference BrakestransactionDb, brakesDb;
   private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Transaction> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Transaction, TransactionViewHolder> adapter;
   int sumofbrakescost = 0;
   String sumofbrakescostvalue;

BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last2);
    bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floating_button);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

    setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BrakesItemActivity.this, BInputActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    BrakestransactionDb = database.getReference().child("Brakes Items Transaction");

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(BrakesItemActivity.this));

    BrakestransactionDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                Object totalcost = map.get("totalcoststring");
                int totalcostvalue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(totalcost));
                sumofbrakescost += totalcostvalue;
                sumofbrakescostvalue = String.valueOf(sumofbrakescost);

            }
            brakesDb = database.getReference().child("Department").child("Brakes").child("Cost");
            brakesDb.setValue(sumofbrakescostvalue);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    showTask();

}

private void showTask() {
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Transaction>().setQuery(BrakestransactionDb, Transaction.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Transaction, TransactionViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TransactionViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Transaction model) {
            holder.item_name_card.setText(model.getNameofitemstring());
            holder.bought_by_card.setText(model.getBoughtbystring());
            holder.bought_from_card.setText(model.getBoughtfromstring());
            holder.date_card.setText(model.getDatestring());
            holder.time_card.setText(model.getTimestring());
            holder.cost_of_one_item_card.setText(model.getCostofoneitemstring());
            holder.number_of_items_card.setText(model.getNumberofitemstring());
            holder.total_cost_card.setText(model.getTotalcoststring());

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public TransactionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.transaction_row, parent, false);
            return new TransactionViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
        deleteTransaction(adapter.getRef(item.getOrder()).getKey());
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void deleteTransaction(String key) {
    BrakestransactionDb.child(key).removeValue();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bottommenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_all) {
        BrakestransactionDb.removeValue();
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home_button) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.back_item_activity) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Department.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

---

THIS IS THE MODEL CLASS I MADE-

```
package com.example.android.zfr.Model;

 public class Transaction {
private String nameofitemstring,boughtbystring,boughtfromstring,costofoneitemstring,datestring,
        timestring,totalcoststring,numberofitemstring;

public String getNameofitemstring() { return nameofitemstring; }

public void setNameofitemstring(String nameofitemstring) { this.nameofitemstring = nameofitemstring; }

public String getBoughtbystring() {return boughtbystring; }

public void setBoughtbystring(String bought string) {
    this.boughtbystring = boughtbystring;
}

public String getBoughtfromstring() { return boughtfromstring; }

public void setBoughtfromstring(String boughtfromstring) { this.boughtfromstring = boughtfromstring; }

public String getCostofoneitemstring() {
    return costofoneitemstring;
}

public void setCostofoneitemstring(String costofoneitemstring) { this.costofoneitemstring = costofoneitemstring; }

public String getDatestring() { return datestring; }

public void setDatestring(String datestring) { this.datestring = datestring; }

public String getTimestring() { return timestring; }

public void setTimestring(String timestring) { this.timestring = timestring; }

public String getTotalcoststring() { return totalcoststring; }

public void setTotalcoststring(String totalcoststring) { this.totalcoststring = totalcoststring; }

public String getNumberofitemstring() { return numberofitemstring; }

public void setNumberofitemstring(String numberofitemstring) { this.numberofitemstring = numberofitemstring; }

public Transaction() { }

public Transaction(String nameofitemstring,String boughtbystring,String boughtfromstring,String costofoneitemstring, String timestring,
                 String datestring ,String totalcoststring , String numberofitemstring ){
    this.nameofitemstring=nameofitemstring;
    this.boughtbystring=boughtbystring;
    this.boughtfromstring=boughtfromstring;
    this.costofoneitemstring=costofoneitemstring;
    this.datestring=datestring;
    this.timestring=timestring;
    this.numberofitemstring=numberofitemstring;
    this.totalcoststring=totalcoststring;
}
```

}

---

THIS THE VIEWHOLDER CLASS-

```
 package com.example.android.zfr.ViewHolder;

   import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.android.zfr.R;
 import com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout;

 public class TransactionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnCreateContextMenuListener{

public TextView item_name_card,bought_by_card,bought_from_card,date_card,
        time_card,cost_of_one_item_card,number_of_items_card,total_cost_card;

public TransactionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    item_name_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_card);
    bought_by_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.bought_by_card);
    bought_from_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.bought_from_card);
    date_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_card);
    time_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_card);
    cost_of_one_item_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_of_one_item_card);
    number_of_items_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_items_card);
    total_cost_card=itemView.findViewById(R.id.total_cost_card);

itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
}
@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
 {  menu.add(0,0,getAdapterPosition(),"Delete");  }
}
```

---

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by putting

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(BrakesItemActivity.this));
```

in onDatachange method like this:

```
 BrakestransactionDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
            Object totalcost = map.get("totalcoststring");
            int totalcostvalue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(totalcost));
            sumofbrakescost += totalcostvalue;
            sumofbrakescostvalue = String.valueOf(sumofbrakescost);

        }
        brakesDb = database.getReference().child("Department").child("Brakes").child("Cost");
        brakesDb.setValue(sumofbrakescostvalue);

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(BrakesItemActivity.this));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to realize that Firebase is Asynchronous, meaning that your showTask() gets called even before your database is able to send you the data. To avoid this issue, you need to put your showTask() inside your addValueEventListener. Try this:

```
BrakestransactionDb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                Object totalcost = map.get("totalcoststring");
                int totalcostvalue = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(totalcost));
                sumofbrakescost += totalcostvalue;
                sumofbrakescostvalue = String.valueOf(sumofbrakescost);

            }
            brakesDb = database.getReference().child("Department").child("Brakes").child("Cost");
            brakesDb.setValue(sumofbrakescostvalue);
            showTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: On putting inside addvalueEventListener, it is showing -Invalid method declaration; return type required

Comment: the app is crashing when I open the activity and showing error

Comment: app is crashing showing this error Process: com.example.android.zfr, PID: 3880
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.zfr/com.example.android.zfr.ItemActivity.BrakesItemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)